# JQuery FadeIn & CSS slide in is choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd6pLaco/1/)

I'm not happy with the current result of the code in the fiddle, I'd like it to be less choppy and just fade in while also sliding in from the bottom but my JQuery skills are not the greatest. Is using CSS as the slide in the best choice? Wasn't able to find any examples of sliding in using JQuery.

Any help much appreciated.

Here's the same code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <style>
      @keyframes slideInFromBottom {
      0% {
      transform: translateY(100%);
      }
      100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
      }
      }
      .v1 { 
      animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromBottom;
      }
      .v2 { 
      animation: 1s ease-out 0.2s 1 slideInFromBottom;
      }
      .v3 { 
      animation: 1s ease-out 0.4s 1 slideInFromBottom;
      }
   </style>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Vista Report</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="card v1" id="v1">
               <div class="card-image">
                  <img id="preload_v1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469461084727-4bfb496cf55a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e7e60237ffbd8c98a087f464f44931c1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80" style="display:none;">
                  <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
               </div>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="card v2" id="v2">
               <div class="card-image">
                  <img id="preload_v2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469461084727-4bfb496cf55a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e7e60237ffbd8c98a087f464f44931c1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80" style="display:none;">
                  <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
               </div>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="card v3" id="v3">
               <div class="card-image">
                  <img id="preload_v3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469461084727-4bfb496cf55a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e7e60237ffbd8c98a087f464f44931c1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80"  style="display:none;">
                  <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
               </div>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script>
    $("#v1").ready(function(){
      $("#preload_v1").fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $("#v2").ready(function(){
      $("#preload_v2").fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $("#v3").ready(function(){
      $("#preload_v3").fadeIn(2000);
    });
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the jQuery scripts and made it work with css alone.

replaced `style="display:none"` on `img` tag with following css

```
.card{
   opacity:0;
}
```

For fadeIn effect changed opacity from 0 to 1

```
@keyframes slideInFromBottom {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(100%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

To keep the animation in final state added `forwards` to `animation` and also updated `animation-duration` and `animation-delay`

```
  .v1 {
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromBottom forwards;
  }

  .v2 {
    animation: 1.2s ease-out 0.2s 1 slideInFromBottom forwards;
  }

  .v3 {
    animation: 1.4s ease-in 0.4s 1 slideInFromBottom forwards;
  }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bd6pLaco/61/)

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for the assistance. Time to study up on cool CSS animations.